# Trying to use two separate flutter audio plugins players and flutter_audio_capture capture doesn't work on real ios device while works on simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, crash, avaudiosession

2023-08-15 00:35:07.255168+0300 Runner[13756:984912] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved>)
2023-08-15 00:35:07.258485+0300 Runner[13756:984912] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved>)
2023-08-15 00:35:07.261739+0300 Runner[13756:984912] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, deinterleaved>)
2023-08-15 00:35:07.262007+0300 Runner[13756:984912] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1397:Initialize: (err = AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInInputChain(ThisGraph, *GetInputNode())): error -10851
2023-08-15 00:35:07.299502+0300 Runner[13756:985197] flutter: PlatformException(ON_LISTEN_FAILED, Error occured in onListen, null, null)

getting this, when trying to use both flutter_audio_capture and audioplayers on ios. audioplayers do work, mic capture doesn't when i use an example app with the same code but no audiplayers, just audio capture - it works. what do i do?

Comment: it has something to do with both plugins using ios' audio interface.

Comment: it used to crash when it had force unwrap on try! avaudiosession.setActive(true) in the capture plugin's ios file. when i got read of the ! it didn't crash anymore but did show this error.

Comment: it also seems to have to do with the expected format of the stream because it says here 0 hz, while clearly it has to be something about 44100hz, although it can be only a symptome of something not initializing properly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.